# osmdroid custom info window not accepting changes

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I'm using a custom InfoWindow layout for my osmdroid markers(OSMDroid version 6.0.3)
Markers are added like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(lat_lon[0]), Double.parseDouble(lat_lon[1]));
                        Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
                        startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
                        InfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.listview_layout, map,device);
                        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);                            
                        startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);                            
                        startMarker.setId(Integer.toString(i));
                        startMarker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                                int d_id=Integer.parseInt(marker.getId());


                                start_details(items.get(d_id));
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                        map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

                        startMarker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

and my custom InfoWindow is an inner class of my activity and is defined as:

```
private class MyInfoWindow extends InfoWindow{
        public int index=0;
        private datalogger de=null;
        public MyInfoWindow(int layoutResId, MapView mapView,datalogger dev) {
            super(layoutResId, mapView);
            de=dev;
        }
        public void onClose() {
        }

        public void onOpen(Object arg0) {
            LayoutInflater l=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout myRoot = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
            View v=l.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout,myRoot,false);
            TextView moreinfo=v.findViewById(R.id.details_txt);
            TextView name=v.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            name.setText(de.name);
}
```

After running my app, InfoWindows show up but the elements inside them have their predefined values from the android studio designer. I also tried using `findViewById()` directly (instead of using layoutinflater) but that returns a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onOpen` method inflates new layout, sets value for a text view in that layout...and than finishes leaving the layout for the garbage collector to be removed. The layout is not attched to a view hiearchy (because `myRoot` is not part of the view hiearchy) so it's not displayed anywhere.

InfoWindow actually inflates and creates its view hiearchy for you. You can access it through the protected field `mView`.

So your onOpen method could be written like this:

```
public void onOpen(Object arg0) {
        TextView moreinfo=mView.findViewById(R.id.details_txt);
        TextView name=mView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        name.setText(de.name);
}
```

For more insight you could check out [the source code of the InfoWindow class](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/InfoWindow.java).

Comment: Ended up using the `InfoWindow(View v, MapView mapView) ` constructor. Which did the job.